# Extract tabel from html code with beautiful soup

Tags: python, xpath, beautifulsoup

I've got html as follows:

```html
<table class="tbOdpis" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="csEmptyLine" colspan="100" width="100%"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="csTTytul" colspan="100" width="100%">OZNACZENIE KSIĘGI WIECZYSTEJ</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I've tried to extract this table with below code:

```
soup.findAll('table')[1]
```

Evrything would be ok except I've received only this:

```html
<table cellspacing="0" class="tbOdpis" width="100%">
  <td class="csEmptyLine" colspan="100" width="100%"></td>
</table>
```

Why the second row has disappeared?

Comment: With what you provided in your question, it is not possible to reproduce your problem. However, a guess would be that the element you're looking for has another index than `[1]`? Might be `[0]`?

Comment: you mind sharing the code where you're pulling this html? As is in the example above, it will give an error as you're calling for tag `<table>` in index position 1, which should be `[0]`. My initial guess is that the site you are pulling the html source code from is dynamic. But can;t tell just by what you're providing above.

Comment: `soup.select('table')` works for me. Make sure you are using `lxml` parser.

Comment: Change of parser from html.parser to lxml has healed my problems :)